# Collections.sort not sorting ArrayList as expected [beanshell, Java, JMeter]

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, jmeter, beanshell

I have some Java code which I am using in Beanshell processor (JMeter). This java code is simple and valid. It should simply sort the numeric arraylist but it is giving strange behavior:

```
// Input data is like below:
   student_id_RegEx_1=13
   student_id_RegEx_11=4
   student_id_RegEx_12=23
   student_id_RegEx_13=24

// CREATE ARRAY LIST AND STORE ELEMENTS IN IT
ArrayList strList = new ArrayList();
for (int i=0;i<25; i++){
strList.add(vars.get("student_id_RegEx_" + String.valueOf(i+1)));
}

// Print the ArrayList created by above method [output is]
vars.putObject("ArrayListBeforeSorting",strList);
ArrayListBeforeSorting=[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 4, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]


// Sort the ArrayList 
Collections.sort(strList);

//Print the sorted ArrayList [below is output]
vars.putObject("ArrayListAfterSorting",strList);
ArrayListAfterSorting=[10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Observe the **28, 29, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11** at end of sortedArrayList. I was expecting  **4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and so on** I cannot understand the reason behind this strange behavior. Could it be because of some issue with 'array input data'? Collections.sort seems to work fine; when I create a sample arraylist myself. Any comments on this behavior and solution would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is your List storing Strings by any chance?

Comment: Don't use raw types, add the generic type to the list so that we can see the elements' type.

Comment: Seems like a correct alphabetical sort...

Comment: Tunaki and AndyTurner, I have shared all the code I am using in Jmeter beanshell processor. Nothing is skipped.

Comment: If you want a numeric list you should fill it with numeric types instead of `String` objects containing numbers. Or you could writa a comparator that orders strings based on their numeric value.

Comment: Thanks for showing the direction Klas, I am new to programming and Java. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: I need numeric order like 1,3,4,10,11,21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving values of type String, save them as numbers:

```
String strValue = vars.get("student_id_RegEx_" + String.valueOf(i+1));
strList.add(Integer.parseInt(strValue));
```

Sorting as Strings works by comparing each character, one by one, for example:

```
2 4 5
| | | |
2 2 3 3

2 = 2
4 > 2 - therefore, "245" is "bigger" than "2233"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I have tried this by putting it inside loop. But it is giving exception error. ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``// CREATE ARRAY LIST AND STORE ELEMENTS IN IT ArrayList strList = new ArrayList( . . . '' : for loop iterator variable:id: null 

As mentioned, I am using Beanshell processor (inside JMeter) to run this code. It supports java 1.5 syntax as per my knowledge. Can you please share a workaround it?

Comment: It seems that not all of student_id_RegEx_ fields are set. If that is intentional, change second line to `if(strValue != null) { strList.add(....); }`

Comment: Thanks a lot Max, this works perfectly now. I have also edited your answer to reflect the exact solution that worked for me. Thanks again.