# Sorting a String Array list by numeric order in Java (Beanshell)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, beanshell

I have following java code that I am using in **beanshell Jmeter** processor to create an `ArrayList`. In the end I need to sort contents of `ArrayList` in numeric order. Problem is that when I use `collection.sort()`, it gives output sorted by alphabetic order since it is `String` `Arraylist`. Can some one share the **java/beanshell** compatible code which can give me desired output sorted in numeric order. possibly a custom `Comparator`?

**NOTE:** This code is to be executed in beanshell processor and that does not support latest java syntax and use of `<>` etc.

**NOTE2:** `vars.put` is **JMeter** built in method

```
// Input data is like below:
   student_id_RegEx_1=13
   student_id_RegEx_11=4
   student_id_RegEx_12=23
   student_id_RegEx_13=24

// CREATE ARRAY LIST AND STORE ELEMENTS IN IT
ArrayList strList = new ArrayList();
for (int i=0;i<25; i++){
strList.add(vars.get("student_id_RegEx_" + String.valueOf(i+1)));
}

// Print the ArrayList created by above method [output is]
vars.put("ArrayListBeforeSorting",strList);
ArrayListBeforeSorting=[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 4, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]


// Sort the ArrayList 
Collections.sort(strList);

//Print the sorted ArrayList [below is output]
vars.put("ArrayListAfterSorting",strList);
ArrayListAfterSorting=[10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Expected output** is sorted like this ... **  4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11..**

Comment: Did you try writing your own custom `Comparator`? It should be pretty easy to `split()` the name, convert the last part to a number and sort that.

Comment: I tried few examples from stackoverflow and net but they didn ot worked for me. I am new to java and could not figure out the issue.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and in what way it didn't work.

Comment: Same question you asked earlier. [Collections.sort not sorting ArrayList as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480031/collections-sort-not-sorting-arraylist-as-expected-beanshell-java-jmeter).

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayListBeforeSorting.get(i).split("x_");
```

Will split your string into the texts and then the numbers in this way:

```
    String[] x = ArrayListBeforeSorting.get(i).split("x_");
    int value = Integer.parseInt(x[1]); //this will be the numeric value
```

You can @Override the **compare** method if you **make a class** for your String you want to compare, and make it use the numeric value as a comparator like this

Make sure it extends comparable

```
@Override

public int compare(Object a1, Object a2) {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(a1.getValue().substring(17,a1.getValue().lenght-1); //Will parse the numbers, since they start at character 17 and they end at the end of the string
    int b = Integer.parseInt(a2.getValue().substring(17,a1.getValue().lenght-1);
    return a - b;
}
```